# Destructuring object in a event handler parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, destructuring

```
const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    setProfile({
      [name]: value
    });
  };
```

```
<input  value={phone}  onChange={handleChange} id='phone-input'/>
```

How its possible that JS knows that target is in the object of the SyntheticEvent?

Why i dont need to do this: `handleChange(event)`?

What if there is a other object with a target property?

I have learned this:

```
let truck = {
  model: '1977 Mustang convertible',
  maker: 'Ford',
  city: 'Detroit',
  year: '1977',
  convertible: true
};
 
const printCarInfo = ({model, maker, city}) => {
  console.log(`The ${model}, or ${maker}, is in the city ${city}.`);
};
 
printCarInfo(truck);
```

Comment: Destructuring does not throw an error if the property targeted doesn't exist, you'll just get undefined.